# Add Images to .xls files in ASP.net MVC and C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xslt

I had a requirement where I need to frame an XSLT file which will basically be be saved as XML Spreadsheet 2003 format (MS Excel) following the tutorial found in [this link](http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2009/08/using-c-xml-xslt-to-create-excel-spreadsheet/comment-page-1/#comment-184716), which roughly looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>9600</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>24000</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62" ss:Name="Normal 2">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s63">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s66" ss:Parent="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Plan Comparison">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="22" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="232.5" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15" ss:DefaultColumnHeight="15">
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">           QUOTE ID:       </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">           ZIPCODE OF BUSINESS: </Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">           EMPLOYER NAME: </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">           COUNTY: </Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">           EFFECTIVE DATE: 04/15/2017</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">           PRODUCER: </Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">           NUMBER OF EMPLOYEES: 8</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">TEST</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">TEST</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">STD</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">        EligibleEmployees</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">8</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">8</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">        EstimatedVolume</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">$1,152.00</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66"><Data ss:Type="String">$1,152.00</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>13</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>2</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Screenshot of the file opened in MS Excel:

[image: Screenshot]

**Issues Faced:**
I tried to open the generated XML file using HSSF, XSSF as well as OpenXml but no luck.

**Question:**

I need to add images in the space marked in yellow in the screenshot, how can I do that?
If it is not possible with this approach, how can I open the generated XML/XLS file using NPOI, add images and download a pure .xls file using that framework?

Comment: See following.  A picture is not part of the excel cell structure and sits on top of the cells : https://forums.asp.net/t/2001688.aspx?Adding+Image+into+a+cell+using+OpenXML+Utility+C+NET+ASP+NET

Comment: @jdweng I am not able to open the generated XML file as a worksheet of any manner. Only if I can open it I then can add images right? any way that I can do a proper conversion of the final XML file to XLS spreadsheet?

Comment: What do you mean by OPEN?  The Open XML is a text file (can contain binary data) which can be edited without opening a workbook.

Comment: @jdweng in the link you shared the method to insert images requires a Worksheet which I am not able to create with the generated file, using OpenXML or NPOI